# Counting distinct entries in a column using relational algebra

Tags: database-design, relational-theory, table, relations, relational-algebra

So I have a table similar to this one. Each user has posted a review about one or more hotels(A,B,C,D) but on different dates so there are no duplicate tuples even though a person might have reviewed the same hotel more than once.

I need to count the number of **DISTINCT** hotels every user has reviewed using **RELATIONAL ALGEBRA** only. How can I do that?

[image]

example to show notations I use:

```
R = ƔUser,COUNT(Hotel_reviewed)->Num_Reviews (InitialRelation- table 1)
```

would give the number of reviews by each user

The result should be the following table:

[image]

example to show notations I use:

```
R = ƔUser,COUNT(Hotel_reviewed)->Num_Reviews (InitialRelation- table 1)
```

would give the number of reviews by each user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the more compact syntax (from @McNets' answer):

```
select   User,
         count(distinct Hotel_Reviewed) HotelsReviewed
from     InitialRelation
group by User;
```

we can also do a projection first to find distinct User, Hotel_Reviewed pairs and then aggregate:

```
select   User,
         count(Hotel_Reviewed) as Hotels_Reviewed
from     
    ( select distinct
               User,
               Hotel_Reviewed
      from     InitialRelation
    ) as D
group by User ;
```

This leads us to the relational algebra notation:

```
R = Ɣ User, COUNT(Hotel_Reviewed) -> Hotels_Reviewed 
        (π User, Hotel_Reviewed (InitialRelation)) -> D
```

Comment: projection doesn't remove duplicates when we are talking about bags, right?

Comment: But relations are not bags, they are sets. SQL needs `SELECT DISTINCT` because it doesn't apply the relational model accurately in that part and allows tables and result sets with multiple identical rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by counting distinct hotels, grouped by user.

```
select   User,
         count(distinct Hotel_Reviewed) HotelsReviewed
from     your_table
group by User;
```

> ```
> create table reviews([user] varchar(20), date_review date, hotel_reviewed varchar(10) );
> insert into reviews values
> ('Joe',   '20170101', 'A'),
> ('Joe',   '20170201', 'A'),
> ('Tom',   '20170101', 'C'),
> ('Bryan', '20170101', 'B'),
> ('Bryan', '20170201', 'A'),
> ('Mike',  '20170101', 'B'),
> ('Mike',  '20170201', 'C'),
> ('Mike',  '20170301', 'D');
> GO
> ```

> ```
> select   [User],
>          count(distinct Hotel_Reviewed) HotelsReviewed
> from     reviews
> group by [User];
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> User  | HotelsReviewed
> :---- | -------------:
> Joe   |              1
> Tom   |              1
> Bryan |              2
> Mike  |              3
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e17e9e44b831832b623ffaeed902109d)*